# C++ Standard Library found in .mm files but not in the .h (Xcode 4.5 LLVM GCC 4.2)

Tags: c++, iphone, ios6, xcode4.5, llvm-gcc

I'm trying to use std::vector in a iOS6.0 application developped in Xcode 4.5 compiled with LLVM GCC 4.2 and I renamed with the .mm extension the files I'm using C++ in. But for some reason, the headers associated with those .mm don't get compiled I've got the following error :

Vector: No such file or directory

I've tried import, include. It works if I only include it in the .mm though.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Thank you

Webaba

RESOLVED : carefully check for other .m files potentially including this header. (not only the one implementing the class) I missed one.

Comment: I don't understand this line: "I've tried import, include. It works if I only include it in the .mm though." ...  can you explain more. What works or doesn't work?

Comment: Vector with capital V? Maybe there is no such file or directory.

Comment: I tried #include <vector>, #include <vector.h>, and #import as well. I wrote it with a lower case but the error msg has an upper case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that ever file including the headers is compiled as an Objective-C++ or a C++ file. You can do this by going selecting a source file, and in the File Inspector of the Utilities panel, you can set how Xcode should compile your file.

The same would happen if you were trying to compile a C source file which included Objective-C headers, for example.

Edit: if the command used to compile contains anything like **-nostdinc** or **-nostdinc++**, then you might have to change your project settings. There should be a setting in the section LLVM GCC 4.2 - Language which is labelled **Use Standard System Header Directory** (for me this is the last setting of that section). Make sure it is set to yes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have 3 files importing the header and they're all of type : "Objective C++"

Comment: Can you go to the build log (right click on the error, and it should say Reveal in Log), and check if the command used to compile contains anything like **-nostdinc** or **-nostdinc++**? If so, you might have to changed your project settings. There should be a setting in the section LLVM GCC 4.2 - Language which is labelled **Use Standard System Header Directory** (for me this is the last setting of that section). Make sure it is set to yes.

Comment: Thank you again. I don't see those flags in the compiler command line and the setting you're talking about is already set to yet. Moreover, when I start write include <vector.h> the auto-completion proposes me the right file so it's weird.

Comment: Ok I got it. 

To list all the files importing this very header I was using "find in workspace" with "import myheadfile.h" and it turns out that another file not showing up in the result of the search (because of an extra space) was actually including the header.

Thank you for your help and sorry for the waste of time.

Comment: Ok I got it.

To list all the files import this very head I was using "find in workspace" with "import myheadfile.h" and it turns out that another file not showing up in the result of the search (because of an extra space) was actually including the header.

Thank you for your help